# AWX CLI export command inside gitlab runner throws 'ApiV2' object has no attribute 'execution_environments'

Tags: gitlab-ci, ansible-awx

I am trying to export all data of AWX to JSON File , with following command, and this command is a part of gitlab cicd, So self hosted gitlab runner executing this command. I tried running the same command on other machine, which works fine. The version of python is same on both side.

```
awx  --conf.host http://{AWX_URL}  --conf.token {AWX_TOKEN} --conf.insecure export -k --job-template > job_tempalte.json;
```

```
DEBUG:awxkit.api.pages.page:get_page: /api/v2/workflow_job_templates/
DEBUG:awxkit.api.pages.page:set_page: <class 'awxkit.api.pages.workflow_job_templates.WorkflowJobTemplates'> /api/v2/workflow_job_templates/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/awxkit/cli/__init__.py", line 25, in run
    cli.parse_resource()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/awxkit/cli/client.py", line 152, in parse_resource
    self.resource = parse_resource(self, skip_deprecated=skip_deprecated)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/awxkit/cli/resource.py", line 220, in parse_resource
    response = command.handle(client, parser)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/awxkit/cli/resource.py", line 179, in handle
    data = client.v2.export_assets(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/awxkit/api/pages/api.py", line 201, in export_assets
    endpoint = getattr(self, resource)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/awxkit/api/pages/page.py", line 115, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("{!r} object has no attribute {!r}".format(self.__class__.__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'ApiV2' object has no attribute 'execution_environments'
```

Comment: I was getting this becuase of AWXkit version, on one side, it was installed as yum package, and on the other side via pip . Now Getting this error,

ERROR:awxkit.api.pages.page:This endpoint raised an error: /api/v2/workflow_job_templates/

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade the awxkit version to 17.1.0
pip install awxkit==17.1.0